# Accessing nativeElement of a component by @ViewChild and AfterViewInit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

**Disclaimer:** My question is close to being a duplicate, however the question itself is not the same.

I need to apply a function to an element that is inside `<ng-template>`, but as it is not loaded in the DOM, I can't do it. Searching I saw that it is possible using `ViewChild`, see how I tried:

**Html:**

```
<ng-template #Payment>
  <input type="text" id="price">
</ng-template>
```

Now I try to access the `#Payment` component like this:

```
@ViewChild('Payment', {read: ElementRef}) Payment: ElementRef;
```

And then I try to apply the function like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.Payment.nativeElement.querySelector('#price').addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    mask(this);
  });
}
```

I get the following error:

**ERROR TypeError: this.Payment.nativeElement.querySelector is not a function**

Now the question for me remains: how can I apply this function on this element?

My goal is to apply a mask to this **input**, which is opened by a modal inside `<ng-template>`. If I put it outside `<ng-template>` it works normally.

Comment: why not us simply in your .html `<input #input (keyup)="mask(input)">`?

Comment: @Eliseo Owww, I understand, your answer was correct. I managed to get it to work, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template#description :

> Angular's  element defines a template that is not rendered by default.

So, in your case you won't be able to access element inside `<ng-template>` unless the template is already rendered, whether directly or indirectly.

Regardless the `nativeElement` of `<ng-template>` is not plain HTMLElement, so `querySelector` will not work. You can use `nextElementSibling` instead.

Comment: Can you give me an example?